# Magento - What is the code for Address line 2?

Tags: magento

For whatever reason, the second address line is missing in my Magento store but I've noticed it active in other stores. Can someone please copy and past what they have for their 2nd address line in the following files:

- template/customer/address/edit.phtml
- template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
- template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Below is an example of what I have for the first street line, but I need to add in the second street line. Also, will there be anything I'll need to change to make this work? I suspect that the core functionality is still there, it's just not appearing on the front end.

```
<li class="wide">
   <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
   <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text required-entry" />
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Note: using `$this->getAddress->getData()` in a foreach loop, it returns the key `street` which has `street1` concatenated with `street2` if `street2` exists.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tried repairing it through proper configuration?

System Config -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options

Change **Number of Lines in a Street Address**

If your template follows best practice, then it checks this config to know how many address lines to include in the templates and database.

Comment: Nick's sample code doesn't show the necessary part that immediately follows it. The next line should check `$this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines()`. If that is still present then your answer will work.

Comment: @clockworkgeek - The files I was using were from the base directory, so that line did in fact exist in the form of a `for` loop. In addition, the value Number of Lines in a Street Address that Fiasco Labs suggested was set to 2. Despite this, only one address line was showing on the website.

Answer (score 9):

Just use one of these to get **all** street lines at once:

```
$this->getAddress->getData('street');
$this->getAddress()->getStreetFull();
$this->getAddress()->getStreet(-1);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. The issue is that the HTML input field was not appearing on the page. I was able to make it appear by adding another text input field below it with similar parameters, but I wanted to confirm that my code was correct.

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear you got it running^^

Comment: $this->getAddress()->getStreet(-1); Did the trick. Tks heaps!

Answer (score 7):

If you have access to the address object, you can easily get each street line with:

```
$address->getStreet(1);
$address->getStreet(2);
```

Comment: In case it helps someone, this should actually be $address->getStreet(0); $address->getStreet(1); since these are zero-indexed

Comment: @NatachaBeaugeais, Prattski is correct--they are actually 1-indexed, at least as of Magento 1.7 and up. Check [Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::getStreet()](http://freegento.com/doc/d4/db8/class_mage___customer___model___address___abstract.html#2d4e85711752e9547902c59c3e63b422).

Comment: on 1.9 they are also 1-indexed. $address->getStreet(0) returns the whole array.

Comment: How can we set it from addressFactory?